# Urban Airship throws error After successfully sending a schedule push notification

Tags: java, push-notification, urbanairship.com

I use UrbanAirship to send push notification and it works like a charm. However, when I try to setup schedule push notification, it throws RuntimeException("Failed to retrieve response from future") AFTER successfully create a scheduled push notification.

My Java application get a RuntimeException but my mobile devices receive push notification as expected. Does anyone know why UrbanAirship throws this exception even when it has sent the notification successfully. It seems very strange and I cannot find any reasons for it. Can anyone help, please?

```
DateTime threeHoursBeforePickup = getThreeHoursBeforePickup(pickUpDate);
Schedule schedule = buildSchedule(threeHoursBeforePickup);
PushPayload pushPayload = generatePayload();

UrbanAirshipClient client = getClient();
ScheduleRequest scheduleRequest = ScheduleRequest.newRequest(schedule, pushPayload);
Response<ScheduleResponse> response = client.execute(scheduleRequest);
return response;
```

My code never reach the return statement.

Answer (score 0):

I still have not found any answer to this issue, However, I have gone back to version 0.3.1 and used documentation from https://docs.urbanairship.com/reference/libraries/java/0.3.1/#send-scheduled-push and It worked with no issue.

So, use 0.3.1

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.urbanairship</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
    <version>0.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```